# Convert month-year to date format in r

Tags: r, date

I have a date that is in the this format:

chr [1:56] "Sep-2016" "Oct-2016" "Nov-2016" "Dec-2016" "Jan-2017" "Feb-2017" "Mar-2017" "Apr-2017"

I tried `as.Date(Dates, "%b-%Y")` and got NA for all the values. For some reason I have tried multiple ways and using different format but it is still not working. I am looking to get it into either 09-2016, 10-2016 or just simply turn it into a date format.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: That question is a duplicate a few times over.  You need a *day* to form a proper date object.

Answer (score 1):

`Date` class needs a day as well.  Easiest is to convert to `yearmon` class from `zoo` and then coerce it to `Date`, which adds a dummy day

```
library(zoo)
as.Date(as.yearmon(Dates, '%b-%Y'))
```

---

or in `base R`, `paste` a day and convert

```
as.Date(paste0(Dates, '-01'), '%b-%Y-%d')
```